# how can i login to yii2 based on md5 encryption?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a table with a large number of users whose passwords are stored as md5,
How can I change my login to the site based on md5 encryption?

**I want forgiveness for a weak English language!**

Comment: I would like just to recommend forcing password change for all of them and go with at least default password implementation for Yii 2 because MD5 is outdated and unsafe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I arrived at the result like the following.

change **sitecontroller** file and **actionlogin** to:

```
public function actionLogin()
{   
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if (yii::$app->request->post()) 
    {
        $model->username    =   $_POST['username']; 
        $model->password    =   $_POST['password']; 
        if($model->login())
        {
            $this->goBack();
        } 
    } 
    else 
    {
        return $this->renderPartial('login.tpl', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and then **common/models/LoginForm.php** change login method to :

```
public function login()
{   
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), 0); // remember me changed to 0
    }
    return false;
}
```

and in rules method comment rememberme =====>>
// ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],

**Explanation: I know this is not the right way, but it's not a problem to carry out your project!**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html

Here you can find guidelines on how to create user model to support authentication, the methods who actually login/logout such users; all the burden to fetch a user and compare password is up to you based on your data model and controllers flow.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest following solution

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface {

...........    

public function validatePassword($password) {
        return $this->password === md5($password);
    }
.........

}
```

You just need to modify the  validatePassword() methode as shown above.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to write this too! yes this section must be change too!!

Comment: @hamid if you find answer as a right the please vote for the same